# Additive loop matlab

Tags: matlab, loops, vector, addition

Say i have a vector A 1x10000 double
and i want to do some operations on this vector, and store it in a new vector B 1x1000000 double(A*100).

E.g. And i want to do an operation on A(1), lets say multiply by 2, do this 100 times. And place the results on place 1:100 in vector B. Then take A(2), and make the same operation, but store theese results on place 101:200 in vector B.

How can i do this?

Ive tried with a double for loop, but i dont know how to change it so the 2nd round gets stored on place 101:200.

This is the code ive been trying to do:

```
    % Random bitstream
msg = rand(1,10000) > 0.5;

% generate phaseshift bitstream with phaseshift +-180deg(+-1)
L = length(msg);

newmsg = zeros(1,L);
for i=1:L,
    if msg(i) == 0
        newmsg(i) = -1;
    else
        newmsg(i) = 1;
    end
end

% t = 0:.1:(L/100)-1;
t = 0:0.1:10-0.1;
fc  = 10e6;
fs = 2*fc;
sint = sin(2*pi*fc/fs*t);

%plot sine
plot(t*1/fs,sint);


%% This is the problem
Tx1 = zeros(1,L*length(t));
m = 0;
for j=1:L*length(t),
    m = m+1;
    if (m < L)
        for k=1:L,
            Tx1(k) = sint.*newmsg(m);
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Can you provide a simple worked example where A only has like 3 elements?

Comment: Post your code, it'll help us help you!

Comment: A = 1x3 and B = 1x6

Then i want to do a loop that takes A(1)*2. And stores that in B(1) & B(2). After that i want A(2)*2 and store that that in B(3) & B(4). And last i want A(3)*2 and store in B(5) & B(6).

I guess it can be quite simple, but somehow i just cant figure it out.

Comment: The code didnt come out as i wanted to. Ill post it soon.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
B = reshape(repmat(A*2,n,1),1,[])
```

where `n` is the size increase factor (100 or 2 in your examples).

See the doc of [`repmat`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/repmat.html) and [`reshape`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) if you are not sure how this solution works.

Answer (score 0):

I hope, this code will solve your problem but you have to modify it a lil bit:

```
a = 1:1:10 ;
b = zeros(1,length(a)*10) ;
for (i =1:length(a)),
    k = ones (1,10) * a(i) ;
    for (jj = 1 : 10),
        bb(1,((i-1)*10)+jj) = k (i) ;
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

First, calculate your new values of A:

```
A2 = A*2;  % for your case, sint.*newmsg should work
```

Then use `repmat` and `reshape` to make a vector B with the appropriate values repeated n times each:

```
B = repmat(A2,[n,1]);
l = length(A2)*n;
B = reshape(B,[l,1]);
```

e.g. if `A = 1:3, n = 10`, the output is a 30 x 1 vector where each element in `B(1:10)`, `B(11:20)`,and `B(21:30)` all contain the values `2, 4, and 6` respectively.